# How to return the particular field from Spring Optional instead of the whole object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to return the particular field from Optional instead of the whole object?

```
Optional<Scheme> scheme = schemeService.findBySerialNo(serialNo);
return scheme;
```

There is the result:

```
{
    "schemeId": 000001,
    "personSN": "0000000001"
}
```

What I want to get is the value of personSN only: "0000000001".

Comment: `return scheme.map(Scheme::getPersonSN)`

Comment: Acctually  it not clear about your expected ouput.

Comment: @daniu: mapping Optional is not available with jdk_1.8.0_144. 
If it is not available in your version as well then check, if Optional is not empty using if (scheme.isPresent()) {return scheme.get().getpersonSN();} else {// whatever is needed}

Comment: @SahilGupta Not sure what you mean, `Optional#map` [is available in Java 8 since the start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-). It does return an `Optional<String>`.

Comment: The way to go with `Optional` is to use it as a *monad*. (Read what a monad is). Please also read [`Optional` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), to learn the basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some weird comments about using get() method on Optional type. Just to clarify - it is not a good practice to unwrap it! Tbh get() should be removed... If you want to do some operations on wrapped object use ifPresent() method, if u want to do some operations on particular field - use map(). Read the documentation and always try NOT TO use get().
Also if u want to fetch the wrapped object, you should be aware that using Optional means that something might go wrong while fetching it so you can throw custom exception as a result of failed fetching

Answer (score 1):

i think u have 2options :

1. create a DTO.
2. using this :

   String personSN  = schemeService.findBySerialNo(serialNo).get().getPersonSN() ;return personSN ;